# Pulling the observer pattern out into a Service

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am a big fan of the Observer pattern. In our code we use it in many places to decouple services from each other. However, I've seen it implemented poorly in many places since there is a lot to worry about:

- Exception handling - don't want listeners throwing runtime exceptions around.
- Long-running listeners holding up the main thread
- Concurrent modification of the listener list as we are iterating through it.

What's more, we end up repeating this code all over the place. In the spirit of DRY, I want to pull out all Notification concerns into a single service. Some pseudo code:

```
Interface NotificationService
   // register the listener to receive notifications from this producer
   registerAsListener (NotificationProducer, NotificationListener)

   // Sends a notification to listeners of this producer
   sendNotification (NotificationProducer, Notification)

   // Sends a notification in a background thread
   sendAsynchNotification (NotificationProducer, Notification)

   // Listener no longer receives messages from this producer
   removeListener(NotificationProducer, NotificationListener)
```

My question is this: am I losing the original point of the observer pattern by doing this? Am I making a mistake by introducing another dependency on both sides of the pattern? Both the Listener and the Producer will now have an extra dependency on NotificationService.

What are your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right with your concerns and questions.
implementing the observer pattern many times seems like plain repetition.
you're also right that the above solution does lose the pattern's objective.

what you've just implemented is a (global?) event bus. it's a matrix of producers and listeners. that's useful for many applications (see GWT's event [bus](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html#events) ).

however if you just want to minimize code duplication while maintaining the pattern. you can remove the coupling between the listeners and the service, use a minified version of the above interface as a member of the observed class. so the logic of registration and notification is written once. 
the observed class is just delegating the registration and notification logic to the service.

```
class ObservedClass implements Observable {
    NotificationService notificationService = new NotificationServiceImpl (this);
    ....
 }

interface NotificationService {
   // register the listener to receive notifications from this producer
   registerAsListener ( NotificationListener)

   // Sends a notification to listeners of this producer
   sendNotification (Notification)

   // Sends a notification in a background thread
   sendAsynchNotification (Notification)

  // Listener no longer receives messages from this producer
  removeListener(NotificationListener)
```

Comment: This is a good compromise! I would probably take the NotificationProducer dependency out of the constructor, so that it would be easy to inject through IoC. The producer would then implicitly be the class which the Notification Service is injected into. Thanks.

Comment: One further comment while I remember - you are allowing a reference to your partially-constructed object to escape into the NotificationService (when passing "this"). This is probably unwise.

Comment: i agree with your last comment, it's better to avoid passing this to the service if possible.